# When to use PID for motor control?

Tags: embedded, pid-controller, robot

I have a project involving a small robot and I need to write the firmware to control the wheels. Its not something I have done before, so I did some research.
In my research I saw that some people use optical encoders and PID to allow the motors to have consistent power.

My question is, is this always needed? I can understand how PID works and what the optical encoder is for, but its not clear to me exactly why its needed.

The robot does not need to track distance, direction of its motors or anything like that. It will move according to time e.g. move forward 2s

Thanks

EDIT:
To clarify on the spec:

- The robot will be given instructions before it starts
- instructions will always be pretty simple such as go straight for 5 seconds, turn left, turn right
- The robot is never controlled by a person in real time, it just executes its instructions and stops.
- It could execute instructions depending on sensor inputs for example if it detects an object using ultrasonic sensor, it may move backwards for 2 seconds.
- The speed that the robot moves is not that important. For moving straight, one speed can be set (using pwm)

Comment: Do you need a speed or position feedback system to make your robot's behaviour accurate?

Comment: Speed isn't important. It should go in a straight line (if its a little innacurate it doesn't matter, it just shouldn't look like its drunk) and it needs to turn left and right and move backwards (all according to time).

Answer (score 2):

As always, what is your specification?

If the robot only has to move, and you are not too bothered about exactly how far, or whether in exactly a straight line, then a DC motor on each wheel simply switched on and off, or maybe speed controlled open loop with PWM, will do the job in the cheapest, easiest way. The assumption here is that the driver (human or some imaging computer program) is looking at the robot and correcting the next move command. With good DC motors, speed is well controlled by the terminal voltage, especially at low and balanced loads.

If you want a straight line, or exact distance, or profiled speed control, then you have a choice of DC motors with optical encoders PID closed loop, or stepper motors. **Be aware that these only control the amount the wheels turn**. If you want accurate wheel position to actually give you to accurate ground position, then your wheels must be **perfect**, equal diameter, running without slipping on a surface with no contamination.

It may be therefore that PID control of the motors is not sufficient to give a good ground position spec, and some form of geographic position sensing is needed. Once you have that, the need for closed loop on the wheel motors becomes less, unless you are trying to hit a very tight position/speed/time profile specification.

I'm not sure I understand what the phrase 'consistent power' means in this context, or why it should be desirable?

Comment: I added some specs for the robot. So if I understand correctly, not using PID could result in the robot not moving straight?

Comment: @gcb Not _exactly_ straight, because one motor, or driver, or wheel might be slightly less powerful than the other, but substantially straight. The key distinction here is 'open loop' vs 'closed loop'.

Answer (score 1):

The most convenient control inputs for defining the path of a mobile robot are speed and direction. If there are two driven wheels, say L and R, the speed and direction inputs can be easily converted to required angular velocities for the L and R motors.

The optical encoders, presumably one per driven wheel, will provide incremental position displacement 'ticks', from which the instantaneous wheel velocities can be determined. So we have two velocity control systems - one at each wheel - and the standard velocity control algorithm is PID. The 'I' term is quite important in this context as it strives to make the steady state velocity error equal to zero.

But beware - the driven wheels will slip, and the ticks will not accurately reflect true robot motion.

Comment: So are you saving even with PID, accurately controlling the velocity of the wheels may not be possible?

Comment: Controlling the angular velocities of the driven wheels is achievable; the problem is that there is slippage at the wheel-surface interface and that means the sensors do not give accurate measurements. This is a common problem in mobile robots. Small errors accumulate very quickly.

Comment: I see. So is there something that can be done about this accumulation of errors?

Comment: That's a challenge. Take a look at some of the literature on the subject. I guess GPS springs to mind, but it's not accurate/fast enough.

Comment: Its a really small robot that just walks in straight lines indoors. It certainly doesn't need to be accurate in terms of position, just needs to go straight enough not to look like its drunk

Comment: A common approach for mobile robots is SLAM - simultaneous localization and mapping. It uses the sensors of the robot ( often odometry ( movement calculated from wheel turns), distance to objects, imaging, ) to create a map of the surrounding while the robot is acting in it. By using its starting point as base, a good system tries to recognize already known parts in a new reading to get rid of the accumulated position error.

Comment: @gcb If 'not looking drunk' is a specification, that can probably be achieved open loop, with DC motors. You may think about adding a trim, to adjust out any residual wheel diameter / motor speed to get a better straight line.

Comment: So by open loop you mean controlling the motors without any feedback at all? And can a trim be achieved with using PWM?

Comment: Your question didn't mention that it walks!

Comment: Sorry, not walk..drive. With wheels!